# Custom filter case sensitive

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I've created custom pipe to filter my data from database

There is pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(aliases: any, term: any): any {
    // check if search term is undefined
    if (term === undefined) return aliases;
    // return updated array
    return aliases.filter(function(alias){
      return alias.local_part.includes(term) || alias.domain.includes(term);
    });
  }

}
```

and there is my search input

```
<form id="filter">
            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="term" name="filter">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

it works fine but I have in my  database records like aaa,Abb,AbbB,cCc.

And when I am typing something into search input it return only elements where is lower cases or upper.

For example: search -> aaa
return aaa but not AaA and Aaa

How should I change it to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pipe as given below

```
private transform(aliases: any, term: any): any {
        let filter;
        let newValue;
        // check if search term is undefined
        if (term === undefined) {
            return aliases;
        } else if (term) {
            filter = term.toLocaleLowerCase();
        }

        if (filter && aliases) {
            newValue = aliases.filter((alias) => alias.local_part.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1 || alias.domain.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1);
        } else {
            newValue = aliases;
        }
        // return updated array
        return newValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the server side logic turn both terms into lower or upper case when you are searching/comparing them. Using `strtolower();` if your server side language is PHP, for example.

The thing is that if you have data that is `AaA` in your DB. And I write in your search box `aaa`:

- I should have as a result the data `AaA`
- There is no logic that can randomly turn `aaa` into `AaA`

So we just turn everything to `aaa` or `AAA`.

Following the PHP example, we could do something like:

```
if (strtolower($_POST['search_data']) == strtolower($db_data) {
    // do something
}
```

**Update 1:**

More or less, with your code, this could be done like this:

```
<?php
include ('db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM aliases";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  $data = array();
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (strtolower($_POST['search_data']) == strtolower($row['searched_field']) 
    {
       $data[] = $row;
    }

  }
  echo json_encode($data);
} else {
  echo "0";
}
$conn->close();
 ?>
```

In this case, we add to `$data` only the data that matches our *search value*. I assumed that the search field is named `search_data` and that the column in your table is named `searched_field`.

Comment: @Defus I updated my answer. You have to send via POST the form with the `search_data` value (the input search) and it will return you the rows that match with that value.

Comment: but how can I send it in angular 2?

Comment: @Defus That was not the question, the question was to *solve the issue of the case sensitive data between the form and the server's data*. But I understand that Angular 2 can be overwhelming at the beginning, so don't worry. Here you can find how to send a POST to the server from Angular 2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#send-data-to-the-server . Good luck coding man! ;)