# Create a pipe to filter exact search in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular app that runs queries over a twitter api. I want to be able to run search queries over the api and pull back tweets that contain certain hashtags. I am using an input search field which has data binding.

So I want it to be an exact search and be **case sensitive**. For this I believe I need to setup a custom pipe. I have done so by following what another SO user has done in a related question here [Custom filter case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867072/custom-filter-case-sensitive) but it is still not working for me. Any recommendations as to what I am doing wrong?

*To be honest, the custom pipe I am using borrows alot of code patterns that I am unfamiliar with and maybe incorrect or not necessary but I can't find anything else on the web (besides AngularJS tutorials) on the topic.*

**HTML template**

```
  <!--Search input field to filter table data-->
  <div class="search-container" style="direction: rtl;">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-icon matPrefix aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Search">search</mat-icon>
      <input matInput #hashtagsSearchInput placeholder="Search by hashtag">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

**ExactSearch Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'exactSearch'
})
export class ExactSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(aliases: any, hashtagsSearchInput: any): any {
        // check if search term is undefined
        if (hashtagsSearchInput === undefined) return aliases;
        // return updated array
        return aliases.filter(function(alias){
            return alias.local_part.includes(hashtagsSearchInput) || alias.domain.includes(hashtagsSearchInput);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use a pipe to filter. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: As JB said dont do it just filter the array which is in `*ngFor`

Comment: use the filter as shown in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-search-filter

Comment: @nircraft I am not able to see the filter function details for `searchText` in that stackblitz link you sent me. How do I set the filter up? Honestly I thought filters were not an Angular feature anymore since Angular2

Comment: What i meant was `| filter:searchText` used in template at the place `*ngFor` is used

Comment: @nircraft Oh I see you were using it as ngModel. Not exactly what I was looking for as I need it to be exact search and case sensitive. I'm also not using ngModel in the input field but referring to it via an ID - then using a custom dataservice class to pull in remote API.

Comment: @dota2pro Hasn't the filter feature now been removed from Angular? I only see references to it in AngularJS and cannot find anything in docs.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs I am talking about Javascript array filter

Answer (score 4):

Angular recommends not using pipes for filtering

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

This is for many reasons, including performance (impure pipes are run on every change detection cycle, and filtering is extremely expensive).

My suggestion would be to use a Subject/Observable pattern to get the desired effect:

- in the service where you handle your data, create a Subject which will emit your data
- create a method which returns that Subject as an Observable with `asObservable`
- implement a method which filters the data by a given string
- have your component call that method based on the contents of your `input` (using `valueChanges` for example, piping in `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` to minimise unnecessary calls — this requires adding `ReactiveFormsModule` to your module)

You could even move everything to a fully `Observable` pattern and move your change detection strategy to `OnPush`, which drastically improves performance. More on that here:

https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Comment: I would like to implement this observable pattern as it does sound like a good approach but I'm at Angular noob level and I just need this done by tomorrow (first iteration) and then I can work on improving and optimizing it. But really appreciate your recommendation.